# In Excel 2007, how can I access the Command Text property of a Workbook Connection using C#?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, excel-2007, openxml, excel-interop

The property is located on the Data tab > Connections > Properties > Definition tab

The spreadsheets in the system I'm working on are refreshed daily using workbook connections which execute a stored procedure from the command text. I want to be able to get this property from these existing spreadsheets and create a list of all the stored procedures currently in use.

I've done lots of searching but I haven't found anything. Possible API's I've researched are  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Basic Pseudocode:
-Open Spreadsheet
 -For each workbook connection
-Add Command Text property to list

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the workbook connections. Very roughly:

```
Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(thisFileName);

for (int itm = 1; itm < workBook.Connections.Count + 1; itm++) {

    Console.WriteLine(workBook.Connections[itm].Type + "\n" +
        workBook.Connections[itm].OLEDBConnection.CommandText + "\n" +
        workBook.Connections[itm].OLEDBConnection.CommandType + "\n" +
        workBook.Connections[itm].OLEDBConnection.Connection + "\n" +
        workBook.Connections[itm].OLEDBConnection.SourceDataFile);
    Console.Read();
}
```